# How to change the default heading of 'alert'

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to use the `alert` method, so the native iOS like alertView will popout. Everything works fine, and the alert gets displayed. But the Heading of the Alert is always `index.html`.

How can i edit the heading of the `alert` method

Answer (score 22):

You'll want to use [navigator.notification.alert()](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.alert) from the PhoneGap API instead. It will allow you to set a title on your alert box.

Comment: [Updated documentation for PhoneGap 3.3](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to refactor your code, you can override the alert() method with a notification :

```
window.alert = function (txt) {
   navigator.notification.alert(txt, null, "Alert", "Close");
}
```

You can custumize the window title : "Alert, and the close button : "Close"

Comment: null causes issues for me, i had to insert "function() {}"

Comment: `window.alert()` is synchronous (blocking) whereas `navigator.notification.alert()` is asynchronous (non-blocking). If `window.alert()` is being used in a blocking context, (e.g. `alert(a); doSomething();alert(b);doSomethingElse()`)  then doing as this answer suggests may cause issues.